# Deja Vu wont restore backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup, 14.04

I have a problem when I try to restore a backup from an external hard drive. Deja Vu wont accept the password, it'll just keep prompting me for the password again and again, I'm absolutely sure that it's the correct one. When I tried running:

```
sudo deja-dup --restore
```

It will start normally but it will wait for my hard drive to "connect", I've tried using different USB ports to no avail.

I don't know what else to do, please tell me, is there any hope for retrieving my files?

Comment: I tried copying the files to my home folder but it happens the same thing ... maybe they are corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

Brow, i was facing the same problem than you.
I did the following: I deleted all from backup then i created a new backup without password.

Right now (12-31-2014: 08:16), Deja Vu Backup is restoring all my files from my notebook to my desktop.

I don't know if the problem was the password, or if was some corrupt file. However, it's working. This is the only thing matter =D